# Logon authentication

Tags: credentials

We have a domain in our environment name "Roofing" in which SharePoint is installed.

We are not able to login if the domain name is case sensitive.
for ex: if I use the user name as:

```
ROOFING\Shinyj ( WITH CAPS)
```

I will receive the same logon page again to enter password.

But if I use the user name as:

```
Roofing\Shinyj ( without CAPS)
```

It works fine.

Hope you got an idea now.

This happens to all the users who have access to the Site.

Do I need to have some specific settings in my environment to have it work anyways?

Comment: The RFCs for domain naming state they should not be case sensitive and to the best of my knowledge that is adhered to just about everywhere. Are you using AD to authenticate or a forms based app?

Comment: Thanks for the response Bunzab. yes we use AD to authenticate. Also recently i have noticed that ROOFING\Shinyj will work only in third attempt. First two attempt always show the error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to access SharePoint using another access method like web services and see if you can authenticate via that. You could try a simple PowerShell script explicitly specifying your creds to test:

```
$pword = ConvertTo-SecureString "YourPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Roofing\Shinyj", $pword)
$WebsWS = New-WebServiceProxy -uri "http://sharepoint/_vti_bin/webs.asmx?WSDL" -Credential $Creds
$WebsWS.credentials
```

If that fails have a look at your IIS log. You should see a 401 for negotiation and then after that it should be 200. If not have a look at the substatus e.g. 401.1 and see if that shines any light on things.

Ideally though you probably want to get your network guys to have a look.